# Is it possible to render HTML into Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug, console.log

I would like to render HTML from a console.(log/info/warn):

```
console.html("<h1>Hello!</h1>");
```

would render…

## Hello!

…into the console panel. Is it possible somehow?

ps.: for the record, I would like to have more coloring options than log/info/warn/error messages.

Comment: why dont you use console.log(document.body);

Comment: Is console.html exist even ?

Comment: you can also use console.table to render an array or array of objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In a way it's possible using the [CSS format specifier](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api#consolelogobject-object).

Example:

```js
console.log("%cThis will be formatted with large, blue text", "color: blue; font-size: x-large");
```

> The CSS format specifier allows you to customize the display in the
>   console. Start the string with the specifier and give the style you
>   wish to apply as the second parameter.

This feature is supported by all main browser developer tools. See the reference for the [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#styling-console-output-with-css), [the one for the Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) or [the one for Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console.log#Parameters).

So while you can't use HTML per se, you can style whatever text you want using CSS to mimic many HTML elements:

```js
console.log("%cHello!", "font-size: 3em");
```

Comment: Yeah baby yeah. Very nice. In my MacOS, works in all browsers except Opera DragonFly.

Comment: Nice, but HTML tags are not interpreted.